# Can i place UIImage in textview as text so that i can delete them as text in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, uitextview

I have to place emoji,text,and images on a UITextview, and have to place all of them as text
so that i can delete them as text. And they will be resized as text in textview
any help!! UIImage can be transfferd in text. And after that adding that text as set text to textview image will be formed and displayed in text view.

```
<p>  i have tried to put emoji on text view and it works well
-(void)selectedFacialView:(NSString*)str
{
    NSLog(@"into selected facial view>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    NSString *newStr;
    if ([str isEqualToString:@"delete"]) {

        if (EditableTextView.text.length>0) {
            if ([[Emoji allEmoji] containsObject:[EditableTextView.text      substringFromIndex:EditableTextView.text.length-2]]) {

                newStr=[EditableTextView.text substringToIndex:EditableTextView.text.length-2];
            }else{

                newStr=[EditableTextView.text substringToIndex:EditableTextView.text.length-1];
            }
            EditableTextView.text=newStr;
        }

    }

    else
    {
        [GlobalInstance.LibCamTopImgArray addObject:str];
        NSString *newStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",EditableTextView.text,str];
        [EditableTextView setText:newStr];

    }
    NSLog(@"  end of selectedFacialView");
}
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using DTAttributedTextView control from [DTCoreText](https://docs.cocoanetics.com/DTCoreText/docs/Setup%20Guide.html) project

Answer (score -2):

The short answer is "You can't place images in your text". 
The complex answer is "You can do it by one of two complex ways".

1. You can create custom font with images (like "emoji"). Notice that copy/paste will not work good in other applications.
2. You can create your own text view for show and editing text. It's a big bunch of work with text positioning, sizing, drawing and font measuring and "CoreText" framework studying. But that's "honest" way.

Notice that some fonts are supports special symbols. Maybe you can avoid using images at all.

Comment: Yes you can, using NSTextAttachments

Comment: We can do it in ios7 by using NSTextAttachments. But for previous versions of iOS I didn't find anything